# Word embedding training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I have one corpus for word embedding. Using this corpus, I trained my word embedding. However, whenever I train my word embedding, the results are quite different(this results are based on K-Nearest Neighbor(KNN)). For example, in the first training, '**computer**' nearest neighbor words are '**laptops**', '**computerized**' ,'**hardware**'. But, in the second training, this knn words are '**software**', '**machine**',...('laptops' is low ranked!) - all training are performed independently 20 epochs, and hyper-parameters are all the same.

I want to train my word embedding very similar(e.g., 'laptops' is high ranked). How should i do? Should I modulate hyper-parameters(learning rate, initializing, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what word2vec software you're using, which might change the relevant factors.

The word2vec algorithm inherently uses randomness, in both initialization and several aspects of its training (like the selection of negative-examples, if using negative-sampling, or random downsampling of very-frequent words). Additionally, if you're doing multithreaded training, the essentially-random jitter in the OS thread scheduling will change the order of training examples, introducing another source of randomness. So you shouldn't necessarily expect subsequent runs, even with the exact same parameters and corpus, to give identical results.

Still, with enough good data, suitable parameters, and a proper training loop, the relative-neighbors results *should* be fairly similar from run-to-run. If it's not, more data or more iterations might help.

Wildly-different results would be most likely if the model is overlarge (too many dimensions/words) for your corpus – and thus prone to overfitting. That is, it finds a great configuration for the data, through essentially memorizing its idiosyncracies, without achieving any generalization power. And if such overfitting is possible, there are typically many equally-good such memorizations – so they can be very different from run-to-tun. Meanwhile, a right-sized model with lots of data will instead be capturing true generalities, and *those* would be more consistent from run-to-run, despite any randomization.

Getting more data, using smaller vectors, using more training passes, or upping the minimum-count of word-occurrences to retain/train a word all might help. (Very-infrequent words don't get high-quality vectors, so wind up just interfering with the quality of other words, and then randomly intruding in most-similar lists.)

To know what else might be awry, you should clarify in your question things like:

- software used
- modes/metaparameters used
- corpus size, in number of examples, average example size in words, and unique-words count (both in the raw corpus, and after any minumum-count is applied)
- methods of preprocessing
- code you're using for training (if you're managing the multiple training-passes yourself)